# window.onstorage event doesn't seem to trigger

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm working on a workaround with a synch'ing parent window, child window and grandchild window. I want to refresh the parent from the grandchild in case the child window is closed and the opener chain is broken. I figured on setting a localStorage variable, my_variable, in the grandchild (when it's opener, child, is closed) and putting the following in the parent onload...

```
window.onstorage = function(e) {
     if (e.key==="my_variable")
        refreshMe();
     }
}
```

I've verified my_variable value by adding localStroage.getItem("my_variable") to a button on the parent. So even when child is closed, the localStorage value does get to the parent. So I think the problem is with capturing the onstorage event. But it seems so straightforward and the parent onload executes to completion, i.e. the above throws no error. i should add this is legacy IE11 rendering as IE 9, but everything I've read said that code should work. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`window.onstorage` is triggered when `localStorage` is updated from a *different* document on the same domain.

Quotting from the MDN reference for `onstorage`:

> "...won't work on the same page that is making the changes — it is really a way for other pages on the domain using the storage to sync any changes that are made"

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event

You'll have to find another mechanism to check changes to local storage on the document where the changes are made.

Comment: Hey, thanks. But this is making the localStorage change on the grandchild window, and I'm trying to catch the event in the parent.....grandchild (sets localStorage)--> child (now closed) --> parent (listen for change to localStorage). As I said, the parent does see the latest localStorage value via a button. I just can't get the window.onstorage to fire or whatever..

Comment: Ok sorry, I'd slightly misunderstood. Are you serving the pages from a server? If not, it might be worth setting up a local host as pages served through `file://path.index.html` may not be identified as the same domain (on my Mac for example, if I load two pages as files from the same directory, they are considered separate domains by the browser for local storage - i.e. the browser treats them independently). From a local host server, they should all be recognised as part of the same domain.

Comment: Thanks. yeah, all coming from a server. The target  window with the event listener is within an iFrame. Do you think that has something to do with it? I tried to change the listener to window.parent.onstorage = function(e) {...etc... but still nothing.

Comment: I think if the iFrame content is from another domain and the listener is part of it, it would most likely use localStorage independantly from the rest of the document. If the domain of the iFrame is the same as the document, I'd image it ought to work.

Comment: yeah, it's really frustrating. I'm able to use the w3schools site, in the same browser, to run the same window.onstorage handler and it catches the localStorage change from a child window. These event handlers are set in onload for a webpage, right?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to change the value in the triggering code:

```
<button onclick="triggerLS();">refresh other pages</button>

<script>
localStorage.setItem("my_variable","0"); // set initial value
function triggerLS(){
    v=1-localStorage.getItem("my_variable"); // toggle value between 1 & 0
    localStorage.setItem("my_variable",v);
}
</script>
```

the triggering code being:

```
window.onstorage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.key, e.oldValue, e.newValue);
    if (e.key==="my_variable"){
         refreshMe();
    }
}
```